# How to add values at the end of Radar Chart points?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, charts

so I am plotting a Radar Chart and I need to add values at the end of each point of the chart. Is there a way? Main area of code and df enlisted below.

```py
"""PLOT GRAPH 1"""

categories=list(df)[0:]
N = len(categories)
 
categories=list(df)[0:]
N = len(categories)

values=df.iloc[1].values.flatten().tolist()
values += values[:1]

for_tick=df.iloc[0].values.flatten().tolist()
for_tick += for_tick[:1]


angles = [n / float(N) * 2 * pi for n in range(N)]
angles += angles[:1]

f, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(8,6))
ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
plt.xticks(angles[:-1], wrapped_labels , size=10)

ax.set_rlabel_position(0)

    
plt.yticks([0,25,50,75,100], color="grey", size=5)
plt.ylim(0,100)


plt.title('Suppliers hit in the test out of all supliers (' +number_of_suppliers+') (in %)')  
ax.plot(angles, values, color='#ffe600', linewidth=1, linestyle='solid')
ax.fill(angles, values, color='#ffe600', alpha=0.3)

plt.savefig(r'C:\Radar\firmy.png',dpi=100)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to find a more manual way, as there were only five values to label, of how to do it, adding this line of code. If I find more intuitive and automatic way, I will update you :)

```
ax.annotate(labels[0], xy=(angles[0],values[0]), textcoords='data',size=5,ha="center", va="center")
ax.annotate(labels[1], xy=(angles[1],values[1]), textcoords='data',size=5,ha="center", va="center")
ax.annotate(labels[2], xy=(angles[2],values[2]), textcoords='data',size=5,ha="center", va="center")
ax.annotate(labels[3], xy=(angles[3],values[3]), textcoords='data',size=5,ha="center", va="center")
ax.annotate(labels[4], xy=(angles[4],values[4]), textcoords='data',size=5,ha="center", va="center")
```